# pass list to exec and fill it

Tags: python, python-3.x, exec

I have the following and can't seem to get it right:

```
newsItems = []

dummy_exec_data = '''
    scraped_data = soup.select("div#content, div.gamma > a, a")

    for data in scraped_data:
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
        partial_soup = BeautifulSoup(str(data), "html.parser")
        title = partial_soup.a.text
        url   = partial_soup.a["href"]
        newsItems.append({"title":title, "url":url})
'''

exec(dummy_exec_data)
print(newsItems)
```

Now i'm wondering if it is possible to pass the newsItems into the exec function so that it can be filled. Currently it returns empty while the block does correctly scrape the data. Seems like the newsItems doesn't see the scope.

Comment: I suppose you could do `exec(dummy_exec_data, globals(), locals())`

Comment: @vaultah: that's the wrong order for the `globals` and `locals` arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass in the object as a local or global:

```
exec(dummy_exec_data, {}, {'newsItems': newsItems})
```

This passes in the name explicitly as part of the `locals` namespace to avoid accidentally passing in too much information.

Demo:

```
>>> newsItems = []
>>> exec('newsItems.append("foo")', {}, {'newsItems': newsItems})
>>> newsItems
['foo']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this solves the problem. However, I was wondering, is this threadsafe?

Comment: @user1213904: no more threadsafe than executing that code directly. Not really.